# How to have the caption move with the image?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i get my caption to move with my image when the page is resized like when the user makes the page longer/wider? and how can i get the caption to move with the image and not stay in place?

Please do not delete my question if YOU feel this not a proper question or if it wasn't stated correctly.

**CSS :**

```
#caption {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #008800;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-align: left;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div style="text-align: Center;" id="photoSection">
    <img  id='photo' src='memchu.jpg' alt='photo' />
    <div id="caption">
        Stanford Memorial Church - the church used to have an 80' bell tower, which fell in the 1906 earthquake.
    </div>
    <div id="forwardOverlay"></div>
    <div id="backwardOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
"use strict";

var photoArray = [
    {filename: "memchu.jpg",
     caption: "Stanford Memorial Church - the church used to have an 80 bell tower, which fell in the 1906 earthquake."},
    {filename: "quad.jpg",
     caption: "The Stanford Quad"},
    {filename: "hoop.jpg",
     caption: "The <i>Red Hoop Fountain</i> with Green Library in the background."},
    {filename: "memorial-court.jpg",
     caption: "Memorial Court (in the front of the Quad) with Rodin's <i>Burghers of Calais</i> statues."},
    {filename: "gates.jpg",
     caption: "The Gates Building - home of Stanford Computer Science."},
    {filename: "stone-river.jpg",
     caption: "The Stone River statue near the Cantor Arts Center (Stanford's own art museum)."},
];
```

I tried :

```
position: absolute;
```

but that didn't seem to keep my caption with the image when the page is re-sized.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle/JSBin?

Comment: Try `position: relative;` See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqh702vp/).

Comment: @sjm yes i can but will the image be visible if i do ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i tried that but i need the caption to be over top of the image at the bottom but it moves to the bottom so i need the caption to stay with the image but be also over top of it.

Comment: Responsive captions with images has been asked a number of times before, try wrapping the image in the same <div> as the caption then these edits-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687819/figurefigcaption-with-floating-image-figcaption-wraps-and-article-text-wra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what your after, the key is display:table on the parent

```
#photoSection{display:table;margin:0 auto;position:relative;}
#photoSection img{max-width:100%;}
#caption {
 position:absolute;
 padding: 10px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 14pt;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background-color: #008800;
 opacity: 0.5;
 text-align: left;
 bottom:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/dz0dyu6v/

Comment: YESSS THANK YOU But question what does the display:table; do ?

Comment: From what I understand it will constrain the parent to the width of child block elements, display:inline will do the same but would not allow margin-left/margin-right:auto